# I want to give user error when update form is loaded and user does not change fields and clicks update

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, crud

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import { Button, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router'; 
import usePrevious from './prev'; 
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';  

 
const Update = () => {
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
    const [checkbox, setCheckBox] = useState(false);
    const [id, setID] = useState(null);
    let navigate = useNavigate();
```

Here I am storing the input field's previous value using another component
to get the previous value

```
      const previous = usePrevious(firstName);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setID(localStorage.getItem('ID'));
        setFirstName(localStorage.getItem('First Name'));
        setLastName(localStorage.getItem('Last Name'));
        setCheckBox(localStorage.getItem('Checkbox Value'))
    }, []);
```

This is where the updated data is being sent to mock api and in if condition i am
comparing previous value with new one(if it changes).

```
const updateApiData = () => {
       
        axios.put(`https://61cb2af8194ffe0017788c01.mockapi.io/fakeData/${id}`,{
            firstName,
            lastName,
            checkbox
        }).then(()=>{
            navigate('/read');
        })
        
        if(firstName==previous){
            console.log("change");
        }        
    }

    return(
    <div> 
         <Form>
            <Form.Field>
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input id="i1" placeholder='First Name' value={firstName} 
                onChange={(e)=>setFirstName(e.target.value)} 
                             
                />
                
            </Form.Field>
            <Form.Field>
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input placeholder='Last Name' value={lastName} 
                onChange={(e)=>setLastName(e.target.value)} />
            </Form.Field>
```

here on button click i am calling the function of sending data to api.
i need to check here if on click update the field's value is same as the previous one.

```
    <Button type='submit' onClick={updateApiData}>Update</Button>
    <Link to="/read">
      <Button>Cancel</Button>
    </Link>
   </Form>
   <br></br>
   <Button onClick={()=>navigate(-1)}>Go Back</Button>
  </div>
  )
}
export default Update;
```